# why pyfftw based on FFTW is slower numpy's fft()?

Tags: python, fft

I run test sqript. It use numpy.fft.fft(), anfft.fft() based on FFTW  and pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.fft() based on FFTW.

here is source of my test script:

```
import numpy as np
import anfft
import pyfftw
import time

a = pyfftw.n_byte_align_empty(128, 16, 'complex128')
a[:] = np.random.randn(128) + 1j*np.random.randn(128)

time0 = time.clock()
res1 = np.fft.fft(a)
time1 = time.clock()
res2 = anfft.fft(a)
time2 = time.clock()
res3 = pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft.fft(a,threads=50)
time3 = time.clock()

print 'Time numpy: %s' % (time1 - time0)
print 'Time anfft: %s' % (time2 - time1)
print 'Time pyfftw: %s' % (time3 - time2)
```

and I get these results:

```
Time numpy: 0.00154248116307
Time anfft: 0.0139805208195
Time pyfftw: 0.137729374893
```

anfft library produce more faster fft on huge data, but what about pyfftw? why it is so slowly?

Comment: You should never profile code this way. `time.clock()` is usually not the right thing to use, you're not disabling the GC, you're only doing one repetition… The right way to do this is to use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), which takes care of everything for you, including the stuff you haven't thought of that needs to be taken care of.

Comment: I find numpy.fft.fft is faster than matlab fft function, too. No idea why.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, spawning more threads than you have CPU cores will not give an increase in performance, and will probably make the program slower due to the overhead of switching threads. 50 threads is complete overkill.

Try benchmarking with one thread.

Comment: Good answer. But really, the OP should try benchmarking with (assuming a 8-core machine), say, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, and 64 threads, to see that it gets faster up to 8 and then starts getting slower again, which should hammer your point home.

Comment: Also, with such a tiny dataset, the code may well be wasting more time on thread startup and teardown, data partitioning and combining, etc. than it saves in actual work, so any useful benchmark should use a lot more data.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is the overhead in using the `numpy_fft` interface. Firstly, you should enable the cache with `pyfftw.interfaces.cache.enable()`, and then test the result with `timeit`. Even using the cache there is a fixed overhead of using the interfaces that is not present if you use the raw interface.

On my machine, on a 128-length array, the overhead of the interface still slows it down more than `numpy.fft`. As the length increases, this overhead becomes less important, so on say a 16000-length array, the `numpy_fft` interface is faster.

There are [tweaks](http://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/pyfftw/interfaces/interfaces.html#additional-arguments) you can invoke to speed things up on the interfaces end, but these are unlikely to make much difference in your case.

The best way to get the fastest possible transform in all situations is to use the [`FFTW` object](http://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#fftw-class) directly, and the easiest way to do that is with the [builders](http://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/pyfftw/builders/builders.html) functions. In your case:

```
t = pyfftw.builders.fft(a)
timeit t()
```

With that I get pyfftw being about 15 times faster than `np.fft` with a 128 length array.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that pyFFTW is actually spending most of its time planning the transform. Try including for example `planner_effort='FFTW_ESTIMATE'` in the pyfftw fft call, and see how that affects the performance.